# Get existing DB item from WebJob causes 'A database with the same name exists'

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I made changes to a working Azure WebApp (where everything was in one project) so that I have the following structure in my solution:

Project.Data

- Models
- DataContext
- Data layer Code that uses the context, CRUD operations

Project.WebApp

- Controllers and views
- Making calls to data layer

Project.WebJob

- Making calls to data layer

Before I added Project.WebJob I splitted out the data context to Project.Data, and I made sure everything worked as it should, and it did. Making database calls via the data layer from my controllers in Project.WebApp is no problem. I'm running everything local for now, using LocalDB.

In Project.WebJob I try to do a simple database lookup via data layer in Project.Data but i get this error:

> {"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\Dev\xxx\WebApp\Project.WebJob\bin\Debug\Dashboard.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}

Dashboard.mdf does not exist on the path specified in the error message. And of course, the database exists on my local database server. **The webjob should fetch from an already existing database, not create a new one**.

In Project.WebJob's app.config I define the connection string

```
<add name="dbserver" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Dashboard.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is the same as for Project.WebApp's web.config.

```
<add name="dbserver" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\Dashboard.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here is my DataContext class where I set the Context class and pass in the key name for the connection string:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Industry> Industries { get; set; }

        public DataContext() : base("dbserver")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DataContext>(null);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: As the error tells you, the WebJob defines its own DataDirectory. Try using absolute paths, and maybe another driver-mode (not AttachFile).

Comment: So you're saying that each project that uses the data layer creates their own database relative to the project folder? @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the connection string to

```
<add name="dbserver" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=dashboard;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This makes a connection to SQL server and to the same database for all projects.